# How to get all members on a type elegantly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been through "**Questions that may already have your answer**" and didn't find the thing I'm looking for.
I want to get all members on a type via reflection. When I try

```
var type = typeof(int);
var members = type.GetMembers();
for(var i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i, 2} {members[i]}");
```

I get 19 members.

I found that some members need specific BindingFlags. Since I don't know those flags and different members have different flags I pass all flags like this:

```
var type = typeof(int);
var flags =
    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.Static |
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
    BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty |
    BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.PutDispProperty | BindingFlags.PutRefDispProperty | BindingFlags.ExactBinding |
    BindingFlags.SuppressChangeType | BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn;
var members = type.GetMembers(flags);
for(var i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i, 2} {members[i]}");
```

It gives me 34 members. That's exactly what I need.

**But is where a more elegant (shorter) way to get all members?**

Comment: Define what you mean by elegant please

Comment: You could "cheat" by doing `var flags = (BindingFlags)(-1);`

Comment: It sets all bits in the BindingFlags to 1. It's a bit nasty though (pun intended... ;) Microsoft's implementation could in theory change one day to throw an exception if an unexpected flag was set. Really should use Adrian's code in the answer below.

Comment: The vast majority of `BindingFlags` are irrelevant for `Type.GetMembers()` and only do anything if you're specifying additional search criteria (e.g. `IgnoreCase` and `OptionalParamBinding `) or affect the behavior of `InvokeMember()` (such as `SetField` and `PutDispProperty `). The only ones that matter when trying to find all members are `Public` and `NonPublic`, `Instance` and `Static`, and `FlattenHierarchy` if desired.

Answer (score 5):

You could use LINQ's `Aggregate` to OR all the different `BindingFlags` values:

```
var flags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BindingFlags))
                .Cast<BindingFlags>()
                .Aggregate((x,y) => x | y);
```